# Sorting a standard array of structs on a variable

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, struct

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [c++ sort with structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873715/c-sort-with-structs)

I am trying to figure out how to sort an array of structs on a specific variable in the struct held within the array.  Here is my code:

```
struct Process{
    int pid;
    int burst;
    int arrival;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    // The number of processes
    int numProcesses = 3;

    //Create an array that holds 10 Process structs
    Process *arrayOfProcesses = new Process[numProcesses];

    // Puts values in each pid, burst, and arrival
    arrayOfProcesses[0].pid = 0;
    arrayOfProcesses[0].burst = 8;
    arrayOfProcesses[0].arrival = 2;

    arrayOfProcesses[1].pid = 1;
    arrayOfProcesses[1].burst = 12;
    arrayOfProcesses[1].arrival = 3;

    arrayOfProcesses[2].pid = 2;
    arrayOfProcesses[2].burst = 4;
    arrayOfProcesses[2].arrival = 1;

    // Sort the array based on the arrival time
    // Help! :)
}
```

I would really like to be able to sort the array in my code on the arrival time. I've simplified my code to give you a general idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.  In my actual code,t he array is filled dynamically from information read in by a file.  **I know that using a List or even a Vector would be better options, but I am determined to figure this out using arrays.**

Any help with sorting this would be appreciated! :)

Comment: What did you try? Did ever try to find solution in web? There are a lot of tutorials and basics on sorting algorithms.

Comment: @DenisErmolin Hey!  I've tried a variety of things.  I seem drawn to a function I've found called qsort(), but I can't seem to make it work with what I'm doing.

Comment: They show what is not working. It's Q&A site.

Comment: This has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873715/c-sort-with-structs (The accepted answer assumes a `std::vector`, but the question assumes an array, and some of the answers address this correctly.)

Comment: @jogojapan - Thank you!  I actually did see that exact post, so thank you for digging deeper.  I was going for more of a standard array using qsort, but as Juraj Blaho showed me below, I can still use the STL sort algorithm with standard arrays.  You have all bee incredibly helpful. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `sort` from the standard `<algorithm>` header:

```
std::sort(arrayOfProcesses, arrayOfProcesses+numProcesses, [](Process const &a, Process const &b){ return a.arrival < b.arrival; });
```

Comment: Thank you!  I ended up doing this:
`sort(arrayOfProcesses, arrayOfProcesses+numProcesses, sortOnArrival);`
I wrote my own sort function.

Answer (score 3):

You can still use your array with STL sort algorithm by adding a compare function:

```
#include <algorithm>
bool operator<(const Process& lhs, const Process& rhs)
{
  return lhs.pid < rhs.pid;
}

sort(arrayOfProcesses, arrayOfProcesses + numProcesses);
```