# Creating a comparison function to sort C-style strings

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, comparison

I'd like to sort an array of C-style strings but I don't know how to create the comparison function properly.

```
//the array
char foo[2][4] = { "abc", "cde" };

//the comparison function
bool cmp(char * a, char * b) //<- actually passing parameters causes trouble
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        if (a[i] < b[i])
            return true;
        else if (a[i] > b[i])
            return false;

    return true;
}

//sorting
std::sort(foo, foo + 2, &cmp);
```

I'd like this piece of code to be as fast as possible so I don't want to use vectors or structures and pass them as a reference.

Any help will be appreciated.

//edit
I apologize for being imprecise. I don't want to re-implement lexicographical sorting because there is an STL function that does it appropriately. The comparison part doesn't really matter. I just wanted to have access to the elements of the strings (in this case 'letters'), do whatever I want to, and influence the std::sort function by returning true or false.

Take a look at the highest rated response: [c++ sort with structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873715/c-sort-with-structs)
I wanted to do the same with an array of C-strings (not structures) - the comparison itself doesn't matter.

Comment: @ShamimHafiz Question is tagged C++.

Comment: I don't understand, it will return true if they are equal and if their first character are not equal.

Comment: How is passing parameters to your `cmp` function causing trouble?

Comment: @jonhopkins `std::sort` expects a begin and end iterator.

Comment: Ah, okay. Nevermind on that part then.

Comment: The comparison function is not your only problem. You can't sort `foo` because its elements are not assignable.

Comment: @Djon, Not first, function will check all(`4`) characters in the given strings. If they are equal, function will return `true`. So, this function is equal with `operator<=` for `std::string`.

Comment: @Pedrom: yes I tried it and it fails horribly, interjay is correct, I'm removing my answer.

Comment: "Take a look at the highest rated response: c++ sort with structs" please note that the answer assumes that you would use a stl container and not an array... this is because stl::sort needs iterators as parameters

Comment: So many deleted answers (mine included), while sorting a vector of strings is completely straightforward...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't sort the `foo` array, because it is a 2-dimensional array. `std::sort` requires that the elements of the array be assignable. But `foo`'s elements are 1-dimensional arrays, and arrays cannot be assigned.

If you make `foo` an array of pointers instead, you will be able to sort it:

```
const char *foo[2] = { "abc", "cde" };
```

You will also need to make `cmp` take `const char *` pointers instead of `char *`:

```
bool cmp(const char * a, const char * b)
```

Other options are to make `foo`'s elements `std::array<char, 4>`, or a struct containing a `char[4]` member. Using `std::string` is the most recommended option unless you have a good reason to avoid it.

Another thing to fix: Your `cmp` function returns `true` when passed two equal elements. It should return `false` instead.

Note that instead of your implementation of `cmp`, you can take advantage of the `strcmp` function:

```
bool cmp(const char * a, const char * b) {
    return std::strcmp(a, b) < 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that absolutely makes sense. I've just tried it and you're right. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

```
bool cmp(char * a, char * b) //<- actually passing parameters causes trouble
{
int lena = strlen(a);
int lenb = strlen(b) ;   
for (int i = 0; i < lena && i < lenb; i++)
        if (a[i] != b[i])
            return a[i]<b[i];
if ( lena<lenb ) return true;
return false;
}
```

You basically need to reimplement the strcmp function. Alternatively, you could use it directly, taking care to properly return the boolean values.

Comment: Actually, your function will compare only first characters of the strings.

Comment: and why one wants to incorrectly reimplement a library funcition?

Comment: It's more clear to write `return lena < lenb;`. You can also pass the arguments as const.